# Can I speed up the tablet detaching for my Surface Book?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface

I have the surface book with the i7, GTX 965m. When I press the button to detach, it takes 5-10 seconds to do. I end up removing and replacing the tablet half quite often in class, so these delays add up.

What I've tried

- Disabling the dGPU from UEFI

I thought doing so would speed up the detach process, since there isn't a dGPU on the software level anymore (Nvidia Control Panel can't open, citing no GPU, and Device Manager also doesn't see it). The delay is the same though and I really can't imagine what Windows has to check other than whether the tablet half has enough battery.

Can I speed up the tablet detaching for my Surface Book?